# jquery choosing one checbox between two checboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two checkboxes. i want this algorithm happen:
if i check checkbox1 i want checkbox 2 to be uncheck,
then if i check checkbox2 i want checkbox1 to be unchecked.
therefore, i need to select one checkbox only.
and i want this in jquery.
thank you..

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkme" id="cc1">Check Me1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkme" id="cc2">Check Me2</input>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#cc1').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? $('#cc1').prop('checked', true) : $('#cc2').prop('checked', false);
});
$('#cc2').change(function(){
    var c = this.checked ? $('#cc2').prop('checked', true) : $('#cc1').prop('checked', false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4nKW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#cc1').change(function(){
  $('#cc2').prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
});

$('#cc2').change(function(){
  $('#cc1').prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Maybe radio buttons are better fit for such case.

**[THE DEMO>](http://jsfiddle.net/z4nKW/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons ensure that only one item is selected:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
</form>
```

<sup>[source (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="option">Option 1</input>
<input type="radio" name="option">Option 2</input>
```

Answer (score 1):

this, by itself is a javascript element and therefor doesn't have a property "checked".

You need to wrap it in jQuery like so:

```
$(this).checked
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this

**Html:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkme"  class="check" id="cc1">Check Me1</input>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkme"  class="check"  id="cc2">Check Me2</input>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".check").each(function()
{
    $(this).change(function()
    {
        $(".check").prop('checked',false);
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
});
```